# Trouble Updating Records with WTForms in Flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm writing an app in Flask that's supposed to serve as a virtual punch-clock for timekeeping, but I'm having trouble updating records.

For existing clock-in or clock-out records (called punches), I want to be able to allow a user with 'manager' permissions to edit certain attributes.  Here's what I have so far:

**the view:**

```
@app.route('/punch/<punchid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def punch(punchid):
    if g.user.is_manager:
        punch = Punch.query.get(punchid)
        form = PunchForm()
        form.notes.data = punch.notes
        form.timestamp.data = punch.timestamp
    else:
        flash('You are not authorized to access this function.')
        return redirect(url_for('user', nickname=g.user.nickname))
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        punch.notes = form.notes.data
        punch.timestamp = form.timestamp.data
        print(form.errors)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your changes have been saved.')
        return render_template('report.html', punches=Punch.query.order_by(desc(Punch.timestamp)).all())
    else:
        flash('Please check to see that you have entered information correctly.')
    return render_template('punch.html', form=form, punch=punch)
```

**the form:**

```
class PunchForm(Form):
    notes = StringField('notes', validators=[DataRequired()])
    timestamp = DateTimeField('timestamp', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

**the template:**

```
<h1>Edit this Clock-Punch:</h1>
  <form action="" method="post" name="punch">
      {{form.hidden_tag()}}
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>Employee:</td>
              <td>{{punch.author.nickname}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Employee Number:</td>
              <td>{{punch.author.employee_number}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>In or Out:</td>
              <td>{{punch.in_or_out}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Timestamp:</td>
              <td>{{ form.timestamp(size=48) }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Notes:</td>
              <td>{{ form.notes(size=128) }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Save Changes"></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
```

**the problem:**
Everything appears to work fine when I hit the submit button.  My server even gives me an HTTP 200 response on the POST. Yet, when I view the punch again, the data remains unchanged.  Am I being a total n00b here and getting stuck on something trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, in the request handler, the form is getting populated in the first few lines with the data from the *previous* version of the `Punch` row from the database, try something like this:

```
@app.route('/punch/<punchid>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def punch(punchid):
    if not g.user.is_manager:
        flash('You are not authorized to access this function.')
        return redirect(url_for('user', nickname=g.user.nickname))

    # only for the initial GET request do you want to load
    # the original data from the model into the form
    punch = Punch.query.get(punchid)
    # should throw in a check to make sure this exists, and abort(404) if not...
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PunchForm()
        form.notes.data = punch.notes
        form.timestamp.data = punch.timestamp
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        punch.notes = form.notes.data
        punch.timestamp = form.timestamp.data
        print(form.errors)            
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your changes have been saved.')
        return render_template('report.html', punches=Punch.query.order_by(desc(Punch.timestamp)).all())
    else:
        flash('Please check to see that you have entered information correctly.')
    return render_template('punch.html', form=form, punch=punch)
```

Also, in the `validate_on_submit` call, you should probably use a flask redirect to a different route that render a template on the same url.

Comment: Thanks reptilicus! This worked like a charm, but I'm still afraid I don't understand at what point the form was getting re-populated with the old data on the POST request.  I did want the old data filled in on the GET request, as you noted, but I thought that everything after the validate_on_submit call would take the user-edited information from the form.  Am I incorrect in assuming this?

Comment: You're welcome! In your request handler, you were essentially over-writing what was in the form with what was in the model. You loaded in the model, then re-populated the form with the data that was in the model that was saved from the *last* time it was saved.